# Button click Getting all values instead of index

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-datatable

I am new to Angular, I wrote a code for button click on an individual row based on the index, but whenever i click the button, it hides all the buttons on the whole page, I want to hide just the button on the row after clicking one of the buttons. How can i achieve this in Angular. Meanwhile i am using ngx-datatable for my table. This is my html code for the table.

```
                 <ngx-datatable  #table class='bootstrap' [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50"
                [rowHeight]="'auto'" [limit]="25" [rows]='leaveInfo'>
                  <ngx-datatable-column name="{{'Employee ID' | translate}}" prop="employee_id" ></ngx-datatable-column>
                  <ngx-datatable-column name="{{'Employee Name' | translate}}" prop="english_name" ></ngx-datatable-column>
                  <ngx-datatable-column name="{{'Leave Types' | translate}}" prop="type" ></ngx-datatable-column>
                  <ngx-datatable-column name="{{'Department' | translate}}" prop="department" ></ngx-datatable-column>
                  <ngx-datatable-column name="{{'Start Date' | translate}}" prop="date_from" ></ngx-datatable-column>
                  <ngx-datatable-column name="{{'End Date'| translate}}"  prop="date_to"></ngx-datatable-column>
                  <ngx-datatable-column name="{{'No Of Hours'| translate}}"  prop="hours"></ngx-datatable-column>
                  <ngx-datatable-column name="{{'Comments'| translate}}"  prop="comment"></ngx-datatable-column>
                  <ngx-datatable-column name="{{'Approve/Reject' | translate }}"  prop="status" >
                    <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row"
                  let-group="group" let-rowHeight="rowHeight" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                  <button (click)="approveLeave(leaveInfo[rowIndex]); clicked = true;"   class="btn btn-raised mr-1 shadow-z-2 btn-info btn-sm" [disabled]="clicked">{{'Approve' | translate}}</button>
                  <button (click)="rejectLeave(leaveInfo[rowIndex])"  class="btn btn-raised mr-1 shadow-z-2 btn-danger btn-sm" [disabled]="clicked">{{'Reject' | translate}}</button>
                    </ng-template> 
                 </ngx-datatable-column>
                </ngx-datatable>
```

WHENEVER I CLICK THE BUTTON, IT HIDES ALL BUTTON INSTEAD OF JUST THE BUTTONS ON THE ROW. Please i need some help.

i have this in my .ts file

```
approveLeave()
    {
        this.hrService.UpdateLeaveApproval(this.leaveInfo).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
            if(data.status_code == 200){
                this.snotifyService.success("leave Approved successfully");
                this.clicked = false;
            } else {
                this.snotifyService.error(data.message);    
            }
        })
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have tried in stackblitz.com , hope these may help you

https://ngx-datatable-responsive-demo-gmkesa.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-responsive-demo-gmkesa?embed=1&file=app/demo-component.ts

Instead of passing the value to approveLeave/rejectLeave function pass the entire row

```
(click)="approveLeave(row);"
```

In Html i.e approve button change the code to

```
[disabled]="row.approve_clicked"
```

In TS File set the row.approve_clicked to true

```
approveLeave(row){
  console.log(row);
  row.approve_clicked=true;

  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dilip, It really helped me, i modified my code, but once i refresh, the buttons enables itself, so you can still click after refresh. how can i make it permanently disabled even after a refresh

Answer (score -1):

As you have a single variable  `this.clicked = false;` blinded to all the rows, so any change on that will impact all the button.

- You must add a property **clicked** in the every employee object you are looping and when you click on row , update clicked property of that related employee object only.